# Format Decimal String in C# using .ToString()

Tags: c#, decimal, string-formatting, tostring, currency-formatting

I have an amount stored in a decimal `result`:

Eg. `decimal result = 1935698.27;`

How can I format that to a `String` using `.ToString()` so that it looks like this: `R 1 935 698,27`

It needs to do the following:

- Add `R` (take note of the space) to the front of the `String`
- Add spaces to group the value in 3's (i.e `R 00 000 000 000,00`)
- Replace the `.` with a `,`

This formats according to the South African Rand currency format.

This is what I have:

```
decimal result = 1935698.27;
string strResult = result.ToString("What should I put here?"); // Need help

// Expected strResult = "R 1 935 698,27"
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is built in - just use the South African culture and the [currency format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#CFormatString).

```
var result = 1935698.27m;
var ci = new CultureInfo("en-ZA");
var strResult = result.ToString("C", ci);
// strResult is R 1 935 698,27
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l3K9aS).

Comment: This doesn't add a space between `R` and the amount.

Comment: It does - see the fiddle. I copy / pasted the output into the answer.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle if you look at the docs for the currency specifier, you can see how you could create a custom `NumberFormatInfo` to create whatever format you liked. It helps that the framework has a default for each culture, so usually this isn't needed.